# How to compare two ANSYS mechanical APDL databases? (.db or .dbb files)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, ansys

I am new to using ANSYS. I use the student version.

Is there a way to find what is the difference between two .db or .dbb  files? I have two files say `a.db` and `b.db`, which are supposed to be the same exact model for a simple beam structure with one point load on it.

One gives as solution for a deflection, which is a little bit different from the other file.  When I open the .db file inside ANSYS APDL GUI and look at all the listings in the GUI, I can't see any difference any where. I looked at material properties, nodes, elements, solver type, etc... and they are the same. But when I solve the model I get a very small difference in result.

Clearly there should be a better way to compare two `.db` files than having to open each and look at each listings one by one and do manual comparison like this.

Is there a command to list to a text file, everything inside the db file, all the tables, etc.. so that one can use some `diff` utility for example to see what is the difference? or is there is some other ANSYS specific tool to do this?

I am using the student version of ANSYS on windows, it is ANSYS APDL mechanical version 16.02.

Comment: Well, some systems can do "diff" or "cmp" and examine files line by line (dif) or character by character (cmp). Obviously there must be a difference somewhere but you are missing it or you made a typo somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a direct method for this. (I suppose you already check command reference PDF).

But one possible solution could be run both models and compare both the output txt file. You can use a website to highlight the differences between both txt files. 
I'm afraid there is no other elegant solution.

Kind regards,